# Как получить время исполнения процесса изнутри программы?

Tags: c, linux

Для простой программы можно получить время исполнения (полное, пользовательское, системное) командой time:

```
$ time ./program
```

Каким вызовом можно получить эту статистику изнутри программы во время ее выполнения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цитата из man-a:
Команда  time  запускает  указанную  команду  с  заданными  аргументами.  Когда команда завершается, time выводит на стандартный вывод статистическое сообщение об использованном времени при этом запуске. Эта статистика содержит (i) реальное время выполнение  между  вызовом  и  завершением,  (ii)  время  CPU,  которое  занял пользователь  (сумма  значений  tms_utime  и tms_cutime в структуре struct tms , которая возвращается вызовом times(2)), и (iii) время CPU занятое системой (сумма значений tms_stime и tms_cstime в структуре struct tms , которая возвращается вызовом times(2)).

Вобщем нужен вызов: times

```
 #include <sys/times.h>

 clock_t times(struct tms *buf);
```

Он возвращает в структуре все интересующие величины на момент вызова, считая от момента запуска приложения.

Answer (score 2):

Для случая, когда нужно просто получить статистику задействованных ресурсов, есть еще функция [getrusage](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getrusage.2.html).